# How to call another prototype async function from another in the same class

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

I have one async prototype function and that is called from another async prototype function. But, I got the error below. How to resolve?

I use node.js v14.1.0.

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: this.saySomething2 is not a function

```js
const Person = function() {
  console.log("CALLED PERSON");
};

Person.prototype.saySomething = async function() {
  this.saySomething2();
};

Person.prototype.saySomething2 = async function() {
  //do something
  console.log("hello");
};

(async function() {
  var ape = new Person();
  await ape.saySomething();
}());
```

**update:**  adding actual code.

```
// constructor function for the KingInfo class
function KingInfo(
  date,
  employeeKey,
  workDayTypeName) {
    this._date = date;
    this._employeeKey = employeeKey;
    this._workDayTypeName = workDayTypeName;
}

KingInfo.prototype.sync = async function(){
  var isSucceed = false;

  let syncType = await this.getSyncType();

  if(syncType === "post"){

  }
  else if(syncType === "patch"){

  }
  else{

  }

  return isSucceed;
}

//@return: "post", "patch", "none"
KingInfo.prototype.getSyncType = async function(){
  let syncType = "none";

  let sql = [];
  sql.push("SELECT count(*) as count");
  ...

  let records = await db_module.query(sql.join(""));
  let count = records[0].count;

  if(count <= 0){
    syncType = "post";
  }
  else{
    let isSame = await this.compareToDataInDB();

    if(!isSame){
      syncType = "patch";
    }
  }

  return syncType;
}

KingInfo.prototype.compareToDataInDB = async function(){
  let date = this._date;
  let empKey = this._employeeKey;

  let sql = [];
  sql.push("SELECT workDayTypeName");
  ...

  let records = await db_module.query(sql.join(""));
  let record = records[0];

  let res = false;
  if(workDayTypeName === record.workDayTypeName){
    res = true;
  }

  return res;
}

(async function(){
  let date = "2020-08-01";
  let employeeKey = "";
  let workDayTypeName = "aaaaa";

  let kingInfo = new KingInfo(
    date,
    employeeKey,
    workDayTypeName);

  kingInfo.sync();
}());

module.exports = {
    KingInfo: KingInfo
}
```

I got this error:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '_date' of undefined

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: this.compareToDataInDB is not a function

**update:**
adding code for db module.

this module might effect badlly?

db.js

```
"use strict";
const mysql = require('mysql');
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  database: 'something'
});

function query(sql){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    connection.connect((err) => {
      if (err) throw err;

      connection.query(sql, function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        resolve(result);
      });
    });
  });
}

module.exports = {
    query: query
}
```

Comment: What version of node are you using? This code works both in nodejs and browser as is.

Comment: I embedded your code in a stack snippet and it runs fine. You can run it yourself to see.

Comment: @Klaycon node v14.1.0

Comment: @Herbert this code has no error, please copy-paste your actual code directly

Comment: @Klaycon added.

Comment: @Herbert your code runs fine for me (replacing db calls with dummy data)

Comment: @Klaycon it has one more error: Cannot read property '_date' of undefined. I added in the post, too.

Comment: @Herbert Did you make it an arrow function again?

Comment: @Klaycon I added db.js code which might effects it badly?

Comment: @Klaycon it looks there is no arrow functions in the code above. What do you mean?

Comment: @Herbert As I said already, your code runs perfectly. So for you to be getting these errors it seems like you may be modifying it and introducing bugs which we can't see. `this` simply can't be undefined in a function expression like that, for example.

Comment: @Klaycon I see. You think that there is no code in my post. Ok. There might be wrong codes in another place. I am looking into it. Thank you so much for your help!